# Convert Array to Object with special case

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

how can i turn this array to an object like below

```
 let arr = ["key1:value1","key2,value2"]
```

to

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

Comment: what is "special case"? What have you tried yourself? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: i actualy tried really hard for a few days , i am still learning , so the help of other means a lot , just seeing others code can help think better to solving problems , the special case is that i don't want the index to be the keys of the object  , thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split by either colons or commas, then pass to `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr = ["key1:value1","key2,value2"];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(str => str.split(/[:,]/))
);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const arr = ["key1:value1","key2,value2"];
const object = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    const colon = item.split(':');
    if (colon.length === 2) {
        obj[colon[0]] = colon[1];

        return obj;
    }

    const comma = item.split(',');
    if (comma.length === 2) {
        obj[comma[0]] = comma[1];

        return obj;
    }

    return obj;
}, {});
```

or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
const arr = ["key1:value1","key2,value2"];
const object = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
    const colon = item.split(':');
    if (colon.length === 2) {
        obj[colon[0]] = colon[1];
    }

    const comma = item.split(',');
    if (comma.length === 2) {
        obj[comma[0]] = comma[1];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `reduce()`

```js
let arr = ["key1:value1","key2,value2"];
var res = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
  var k = c.split(/[:,]/)[0];
  var v = c.split(/[:,]/)[1];
  a[k] = v;
  return a
},{});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work; the `array` items can be either `:` or `,` separated, not just colon.

Comment: the input array was probably just a typo by the author... tip `var [k,v] = c.split(/[:,]/)`